# converting sql-server to postgres issues

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

I am trying to convert from SQL Server to PostgreSQL and having some issues with this part here. The error I am getting is.

```
Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason:
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
  Position: 54940
```

Code:

```
                    IF (par_show_new_columns = 'N') THEN
                        begin
                            INSERT INTO TEMPORARY TABLE t$lowlevedetail select c.cusip, c.low_level_value, c.rule_type, c.sector, c.emerging_fl, c.cpn_type, c.funding, c.lehman_industry, c.lehman_industry_desc, c.lehman_sector_cd, c.lehman_sector_desc, c.lehman_sub_sector_cd, c.lehman_sub_sector_desc, c.p_shock_sector_desc, c.issuer_ticker, c.bondtype, c.sm_sec_group, c.sm_sec_type, c.sec_type, c.region_block, c.risk_country, c.country_name, c.currency, c.currency_name, c.structure, c.priority, c.group1, c.group2, c.group3, c.sort_order, c.spec_type, c.state, c.desc_instmt, c.brs_sector, c.sic_code, c.liquid_flag, c.days_to_maturity          ,p.composite_name,
                                                p.p_source, p.index_fl, p.cur_par
                                                , p.base_mv
                                                , p.base_mv/t.base_mv as base_mv_pct
                                                , p.base_mv/t.gross_base_mv as gross_base_mv_pct
                                                , p.base_nmv
                                                , p.base_nmv/t.base_mv as base_nmv_pct
                                                , p.base_nmv/t.gross_base_mv as gross_base_nmv_pct
                                                ,case when p.base_mv=0 then 0 else (p.eff_ddur * p.base_nmv)/p.base_mv end as eff_ddur
                                                ,case when t.base_mv=0 then 0 else (p.eff_ddur * p.base_nmv)/t.base_mv end as dur_contrib
                                                ,case when (t.dur_contrib*t.base_mv)=0 then 0 else (p.eff_ddur * p.base_nmv)/(t.dur_contrib*t.base_mv) end as dur_contrib_pct
                                                ,case when p.base_mv=0 then 0 else (p.spread_dur * p.base_nmv)/p.base_mv end as spread_dur
                                                ,case when t.base_mv=0 then 0 else (p.spread_dur * p.base_nmv)/t.base_mv end as spread_dur_contrib
                                                ,case when (t.spread_dur_contrib*t.base_mv)=0 then 0 else (p.spread_dur * p.base_nmv)/(t.spread_dur_contrib*t.base_mv) end as spread_dur_contrib_pct
                                            from t$pos p, t$intCusips c,  t$tmpSectorTotal t
                                            where p.cusip = c.cusip
                                            and p.composite_name = t.composite_name;
                        END;
```

The original script looked like:

```
            begin
                /* Adaptive Server has expanded all '*' elements in the following statement */ select c.cusip, c.low_level_value, c.rule_type, c.sector, c.emerging_fl, c.cpn_type, c.funding, c.lehman_industry, c.lehman_industry_desc, c.lehman_sector_cd, c.lehman_sector_desc, c.lehman_sub_sector_cd, c.lehman_sub_sector_desc, c.p_shock_sector_desc, c.issuer_ticker, c.bondtype, c.sm_sec_group, c.sm_sec_type, c.sec_type, c.region_block, c.risk_country, c.country_name, c.currency, c.currency_name, c.structure, c.priority, c.group1, c.group2, c.group3, c.sort_order, c.spec_type, c.state, c.desc_instmt, c.brs_sector, c.sic_code, c.liquid_flag, c.days_to_maturity          ,p.composite_name,
                    p.p_source, p.index_fl, p.cur_par
                    , p.base_mv
                    , p.base_mv/t.base_mv as base_mv_pct
                    , p.base_mv/t.gross_base_mv as gross_base_mv_pct
                    , p.base_nmv
                    , p.base_nmv/t.base_mv as base_nmv_pct
                    , p.base_nmv/t.gross_base_mv as gross_base_nmv_pct
                    ,case when p.base_mv=0 then 0 else (p.eff_ddur * p.base_nmv)/p.base_mv end as eff_ddur
                    ,case when t.base_mv=0 then 0 else (p.eff_ddur * p.base_nmv)/t.base_mv end as dur_contrib
                    ,case when (t.dur_contrib*t.base_mv)=0 then 0 else (p.eff_ddur * p.base_nmv)/(t.dur_contrib*t.base_mv) end as dur_contrib_pct
                    ,case when p.base_mv=0 then 0 else (p.spread_dur * p.base_nmv)/p.base_mv end as spread_dur
                    ,case when t.base_mv=0 then 0 else (p.spread_dur * p.base_nmv)/t.base_mv end as spread_dur_contrib
                    ,case when (t.spread_dur_contrib*t.base_mv)=0 then 0 else (p.spread_dur * p.base_nmv)/(t.spread_dur_contrib*t.base_mv) end as spread_dur_contrib_pct
                into #lowlevedetail
                from #pos p, #intCusips c,  #tmpSectorTotal t
                where p.cusip = c.cusip
                and p.composite_name = t.composite_name
                --order by c.group1, c.group2, c.group3
```

Comment: Hm. That doesn't look like SQL at all. There are keywords like `IF`, `BEGIN` or `END`. What language is this?

Comment: Please show us the full code of your stored procedure.

Comment: There is no `insert into temporary table ...` in Postgres (or standard SQL). Only `insert into ...`

Comment: Comma joins went away with the SQL-92 specification 30 years ago.

Comment: If you have a script with 54940 characters you have a far bigger problem already. This isn't valid T-SQL either - there's no `INSERT INTO TEMPORARY TABLE`. What is the *original* script you want to convert? And why is it so huge?

Comment: I have added the original script

Answer (score 0):

If you have `vim` editor, i would suggest you perform below steps:

1. Open file in `vim`
2. :goto 54940

This will take you to the 54940 byte location.